# Woocommerce "read more" instead of "add to cart"

Tags: read-more

Right now my shop have this "add to cart" button. How can I replace this with a "read more" or "show more" button?

The "read more" button should link to the product page instead of just add it to the cart.

Can I add a something to the `functions.php` to call this? I guess this function is built into the system?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace *add to cart* **in general**, do it like so:

```
function wpse_124826_add_to_cart_text() {
    return 'read more';
} // function wpse_124826_add_to_cart_text
add_filter('add_to_cart_text', 'wpse_124826_add_to_cart_text');
```